# <a4j:repeat> does not load values

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

I want to display list of scripts. I am using `<a4j:repeat>` but it does not load any items. 
I debugged and noticed that the getScripts() method is not called at all.
The JSP code is:

```
      <a4j:repeat value="#{ModifyScriptBean.scripts}" var="script"  >
           <h:outputText  value="#{script.name}"  />  
      </a4j:repeat>
```

Backing bean is:

```
     private List<Script> scripts;
     public List<Script> getScripts() {   
         return scripts;
     }


     public void setScripts(List<Script> scripts) {
        this.scripts = scripts;
     }
```

Comment: Do you have log error?

Comment: Looks like your `<a4j:repeat>` is inside a component with `rendered="false"` property. Make sure to test this in a simple and clean view before trying it in your real view.

Comment: Could you try to print something static inside your loop, like your name or something. That will give you an idea regarding whether a4j is looping properly or not. 1 more thing worth checking will be printing size of the list to be iterated outside a4j:repeat, to get an idea about whether the data is coming correctly from Server side or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the a4j taglib in the JSP page?

```
<%@taglib prefix="a4j" uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" %>
```

Comment: If doesn't, then the page would have shown an error while parsing the JSP/Facelets file.

Comment: Any other a4j component works properly in this page? Do you try to use <c:forEach>, just to see if works?